# How to extract specific text from JSON using BASH

Tags: json, bash, sed

I have copy-pasted the JSON structure into a .txt file for my input file (I will have a number of these).

I'm looking for the "Name" text between "start" and "end", my input file is large and the parts I want to extract from look like this:

```
Here: "start",
        title: "Name",
        type: "end",
        words: "more words",
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
input.txt < sed -n '/^start",$/,/^type: "end"$/p' data > output.txt
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-sed-and-awk

Answer (score 1):

data.txt

```
...
Here: "start",
        title: "Name",
        type: "end",
        words: "more words",
...
```

Sed command:

```
 $ sed -n '/start",$/,/ *type: "end",$/p' data.txt
```

Output:

```
Here: "start",
        title: "Name",
        type: "end",
```

^ won't match the start line since there's a "Here:" before it and "end"$ won't match the end line since there's a comman after the last quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

With the sample input you posted this is all you need:

```
$ awk -F\" '/end/{print t} {t=$2}' file
Name
```

If that's not adequate then come up with more truly representative sample input that includes the cases you think will be difficult for a script to deal with.
It's always trivial to extract the text you want and MUCH harder to not extract text you don't want.